# Clamp node to screen bounds

Tags: sprite-kit, bounds, touchesmoved

```
 override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

            var translation = CGPointMake(location.x - previousLocation.x, location.y - previousLocation.y)
crossHair.position = CGPointMake(crossHair.position.x  + translation.x * 3, crossHair.position.y + translation.y * 3)
   }
    }
```

I have a crosshair on the screen and i can move it using touchesmoved as shown above, but my problem is i don't know how to prevent it from going of the screen. there is the `fmaxf` & `fminf` but i am not entirely sure how to use them, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the `node` inside the coordinates using the following code. The following code only checks if the position of the sprite is within the bounds. I assumed the position is at the centre of the sprite.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        var translation = CGPointMake(location.x - previousLocation.x, location.y - previousLocation.y)
        var positionX : CGFloat = crossHair.position.x + translation.x * 3
        var positionY : CGFloat = crossHair.position.y + translation.y * 3

        if positionX < 0 {
            positionX = 0
        }
        else if positionX > self.size.width
        {
            positionX = self.size.width
        }

        if positionY < 0 {
            positionY = 0
        }
        else if positionY > self.size.height
        {
            positionY = self.size.height
        }

        crossHair.position = CGPointMake(positionX, positionY)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting the position of the crosshair, check whether it is not outside of the screen:

```
var x = crossHair.position.x;
var y = crossHair.position.y; 
if(crossHair.position.x > self.size.width) {
  x = self.size.width;
}
if(crossHair.position.x < 0) {
 x = 0;
}
if(crossHair.position.y > self.size.height) {
  y = self.size.height;
}
if(crossHair.position.y < 0) {
 y = 0;
}

crossHair.position = CGPointMake(x,y);
```